# (objective C - Xcode) Download app from server and store it on OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a OSX app running on my machine. There is also an updater app on the server. Once my app starts I check for the version of the app with the one on the server.

If they mismatch, I have to download the updater app from the server and store it on my mac and run it so that a new bundle gets created with the latest version.

How can I go about doing this. Any help would be great as I need to get this sorted asap. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Your question is too broad to be a good fit here.

Comment: Just need a direction as to how I can proceed. Like a NSURL request to receive data or anything that makes this easier. I am not sure how  to proceed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out the [Sparkle framework](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/).  It's an open source framework that does this very thing.

Comment: Is there a way I  could cook up a quick installer app that does the delete/replace bundle into the Application folder and not rely on third party library for now?